# Implementing Loss Function for FCN on Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to implement a loss function for an FCN. My output is a tensor of shape (n, c, h, w). My target is of shape (h, w). I would like to calculate a loss between the output and the tensor but the problem is that I have a mask. There is only a certain portion of the image that I am interested in calculating the loss for and training on (I would like to ignore the rest). I am trying to achieve my goal by unwrapping the image into arrays and then applying the mask on it. Then I would calculate the loss. When I do this, I receive an error:

> RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes’ failed. at /pytorch/aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:93

Please see my code (There may be an easier way to do this as I am new to this):

```py
def Loss(inp, target, mask):
    mask=torch.from_numpy(np.array(mask, dtype=np.uint8))
    target=target.contiguous().view(-1,1) #Flattening the Target Image
    mask = mask.contiguous().view(-1, 1) #Flattening Mask
    target = target[~mask] #Masking Target
    n, c, h, w = inp.size()
    inp1=np.zeros((target.shape[0],c)) #Creating new empty array with dimensions of (masked_region, c)
    inp1=torch.from_numpy(inp1)
    for i in range( c):
        inp1[:,i]=inp[0,i,:,:].view(-1,1)[~mask] #Masking the input and filling in the array created
    log_p = F.log_softmax(inp1, dim=1)
    criterion=nn.NLLLoss()
    loss = criterion(log_p, target)
    return loss
```

Comment: why would you ignore the masked part of the image when calculating the loss? IMHO the loss relates to the image with the mask.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `inp` and `target` variable are both tensors representing images I fail to see why you required the application of `log_softmax` and why you would use `NLLLoss` as your loss function.

Try scrapping the softmax and using `MSELoss` as your loss function, here's an example using your code:

```
def Loss(inp, target, mask):
    mask=torch.from_numpy(np.array(mask, dtype=np.uint8))
    target=target.contiguous().view(-1,1) #Flattening the Target Image
    mask = mask.contiguous().view(-1, 1) #Flattening Mask
    target = target[~mask] #Masking Target
    n, c, h, w = inp.size()
    inp1=np.zeros((target.shape[0],c)) #Creating new empty array with dimensions of (masked_region, c)
    inp1=torch.from_numpy(inp1)
    for i in range( c):
        inp1[:,i]=inp[0,i,:,:].view(-1,1)[~mask] #Masking the input and filling in the array created
    criterion=nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
    loss = criterion(inp1, target)
    return loss
```

Comment: The target is actually a segmented image with pixel wise labels that are 0 - 9. MSE would not be the correct loss function for a categorical target? Also the output of my FCN is 10 channels for each image.